# Where can I find the Product-Name-Swift.h file?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm NOT looking for the "ProductName-Bridging-Header.h" file. I'm looking for the file that exposes Swift symbols to the Objective-C compiler in a project that has both Objective-C and Swift source files. I believe it's in some pretty obscure directory that is not within the project directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It lives in DerivedData, namely the DerivedSources folder.

`~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproject-[some junk]/Build/Intermediates/myproject.build/[configuration]/myproject.build/DerivedSources/myproject-Swift.h`

You can find it more easily by ⌘-clicking on the `#import` directive.